# How to custom format a number in SPSS, like putting percentages between parenthesis?

Tags: spss

How to custom format a number in SPSS, like putting percentages between parenthesis? Any help is appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of output tables do you want to change? In `ctable` you have many options, but in others it typically takes a custom script. Also check out the [modify tables](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/files/app/person/270002VCWN/file/e14c8e78-d189-447b-99fb-11eeff6d14e9?lang=en) python extension, you can do alot of different manipulations after the table is already generated.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctables` give you extensive control over output cell formats.  Most other procedures use a combination of a variable's format and the type of output statistic to construct the format.  If you use a custom currency format (defined via `Edit > Options > Currency`) you have a lot of control over the format.

With `SPSSINC MODIFY TABLES`, you can set a cell format using one of the custom functions included with the command.  Here is an example.

```
FREQUENCIES var
SPSSINC MODIFY TABLES subtype="frequencies"
SELECT "Percent" "Valid Percent" "Cumulative Percent"
STYLES CUSTOMFUNCTION='customstylefunctions.SetNumericFormat(format="##.#%")'
```

The formats are referenced the way you see them if you double click a table, select a cell, and chose Cell Formats.  This command selects column with the listed labels and changes the cell formats.

To run this command, you need to install the Python Essentials from the [SPSS Community website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral).  With V19 or later, this command is installed with the Essentials.

HTH,
Jon Peck

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. I think a slash is missing before the Keyword style: 
SPSSINC MODIFY TABLES subtype="frequencies"
SELECT "Percent" "Valid Percent" "Cumulative Percent"
/STYLES CUSTOMFUNCTION='customstylefunctions.SetNumericFormat(format="##.#%")'

Comment: Yes, STYLES is a subcommand.  FREQUENCIES var should end with a period as should the entire MODIFY TABLES command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SPSS v22 or higher, you could use `OUTPUT MODIFY` to fine-tune output.

This removes the percent signs in the data values of all pivot tables:

```
get file = "samples\English\Employee data.sav".
crosstabs educ by gender /cells=row.
output modify /select tables /tablecells select=[body]  format="f10.2".
```

Custom formats (CCA thru CCD) may also be used. Also, the effect of `OUTPUT MODIFY` may be limited to certain OMS (sub)types. The following parenthesizes negative values, provided that the OMS subtype is equal to ' Report'. OMS subtypes may be found by right-clicking the output item. OMS stands for "Output Management System".

```
if ( mod($casenum, 2) eq 0 )  salary = - salary.  /*create some negative values.
summarize salary /cells = min mean max.
set cca "(-,,,)".  /* negative values are parenthesized.
output modify /select tables /if subtypes=['Report'] /tablecells select=[body] format="cca".
```